# Is there a way to create a (compressed) squashfs that contains an uncompressed file

Tags: linux, filesystems, compression, squashfs

We have a large file that needs to be uncompressed inside a compressed squashfs.

Is this possible without patching mksquashfs?

---

Something like this would be nice:

```
$ mksquashfs existing_squash.sqsh 
             -uncompressed my_big_file.txt
             new_squash.sqsh
```

Comment: Why do you want the file uncompressed?

Comment: Because when the file(s) is uncompressed it takes 0.5 seconds to read.

When the file is compressed, it takes 2.5 seconds to uncompress and read.

Answer (score 0):

There didn't seem like a straightforward way of doing the above, so we decided to copy that large file to an uncompressed location once when we copy the flash to the device.